# This app may have issues in the web version of Teams

Tags: teams-toolkit, microsoft-teams-js

I've recently been working on developing a Teams app and updated the Teams JS version to the latest one ("@microsoft/teams-js": "^2.21.0").

However, upon opening the Teams app, I encountered a message stating, "***This app may have issues in the web version of Teams***." This is concerning as the app was previously functioning without any problems. What could be causing this issue, and how can it be resolved?

> This app may have issues in the web version of Teams However, it
> should work just fine from Teams Desktop. Open Teams desktop Show the
> app anyway

[image]